# Прежнее значение для функции calc()

Tags: css, css3, margin

Есть макет, на котором в навигации у элементов списка разные отступы слева друг от друга. Я задал общий класс всем элементам и через `:nth-child` для каждого задал значение.

Вопрос: как получить эти значения отступов для функции `calc()`, чтобы в дальнейшем через медиа-запрос их перестроить?

Comment: Не понятно, за чем получать эти значения... Пропиши те стили в медиа, которые нужны... Чего-то вопрос не внятный...  Или же автор не имеет представления, что такое `@media` и с чем его едят..

Answer (score 0):

Через `js` можно, либо через препроцессоры типа `SASS / LESS`.

Пример через `js`:

```
document.querySelector('#elem').style.margin
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/259867)

Comment: Согласен что не является но и на нативном `css` это не сделать. Я лишь дал наводку в какую сторону смотреть

Comment: А `js` тут при чем....  ? Все делается чистым `css`...  Ну или я вопроса не понял или ты...

Comment: Да возможно кто то из нас не понял вопроса , но я понял так: автор хочет получить значение `margin` определённого блока. Поэтому и написал строку выше, если автор имел введу другое я обязательно удалю ответ.